# Can't build source code for "Unix Network Programming: Interprocess Communication"

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using Linux Mint 13 and I am studying the book "Unix Network Programming: Interprocess Communication". I downloaded the source code of the book - http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.html - and followed the instructions.

First, I ran ./configure in the base directory

Then, I went into the lib directory and ran make. This gives the following error -

```
gcc -c  "/home/linux/Code/c/unix_network_programming/main.c" -g  -o ./Debug/main.o "-I." "-I." 
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/stdint.h:3:0,
                 from /usr/include/netinet/in.h:24,
                 from /usr/include/rpc/types.h:91,
                 from /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h:38,
                 from /home/linux/Code/c/unix_network_programming/unpipc.h:115,
                 from /home/linux/Code/c/unix_network_programming/main.c:2:
/usr/include/stdint.h:49:24: error: duplicate ‘unsigned’
/usr/include/stdint.h:49:24: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/stdint.h:50:28: error: duplicate ‘unsigned’
/usr/include/stdint.h:50:28: error: duplicate ‘short’
/usr/include/stdint.h:52:23: error: duplicate ‘unsigned’
/usr/include/stdint.h:52:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
```

Here's the file that is giving the error -

```
#ifndef _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#if __STDC_HOSTED__
# include_next <stdint.h>
#else
# include "stdint-gcc.h"
#endif
#define _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#endif
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error as I have very little C experience?

Comment: you could run `autoconf` to rebuild the configure script.

Comment: Yuck yuck yuck! The problem is in AC_UNP_CHECK_TYPE, a rather unpleasant macro. The issue is that the code is written for slightly older systems that don't have stdint.h, which is getting pulled in by your system's netinet headers. The yuck is that AC_UNP_CHECK_TYPE does a "#define uint8_t unsigned char" instead of using a typedef, so everything blows up when the real uint8_t is brought into play.

Comment: could it be the the unpipc.h from the book is trying to define some types defined in stdint?

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it? I haven't the slightest clue, I have very little experience with the C environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the following, mildly nasty patch:

```
diff -U 3 ./aclocal.m4 ./aclocal.m4
--- ./aclocal.m4       1997-10-10 22:45:46.000000000 +0100
+++ ./aclocal.m4        2013-03-25 17:35:22.287397177 +0000
@@ -31,6 +31,7 @@
                AC_TRY_COMPILE(
 [
 #include       "confdefs.h"    /* the header built by configure so far */
+#include <stdint.h>
 #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
 #  include     <sys/types.h>
 #endif
diff -U 3 ../unpv22e/config.h.in ./config.h.in
--- ./config.h.in      1998-06-10 18:26:41.000000000 +0100
+++ ./config.h.in       2013-03-25 17:42:18.788139903 +0000
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@
 #undef CPU_VENDOR_OS

 /* *INDENT-OFF* */
+#undef HAVE_STDINT_H
 #undef HAVE_DOOR_H                             /* <door.h> */
 #undef HAVE_MQUEUE_H                           /* <mqueue.h> */
 #undef HAVE_POLL_H                             /* <poll.h> */
@@ -49,6 +50,9 @@
 #undef HAVE_DEV_ZERO

 /* Define the following to the appropriate datatype, if necessary */
+#ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
+#include <stdint.h>
+#endif
 #undef int8_t                          /* <sys/types.h> */
 #undef int16_t                         /* <sys/types.h> */
 #undef int32_t                         /* <sys/types.h> */
diff -U 3 ../unpv22e/configure.in ./configure.in
--- ./configure.in     1998-06-06 22:42:29.000000000 +0100
+++ ./configure.in      2013-03-25 17:38:14.555324559 +0000
@@ -105,7 +105,7 @@
 dnl but used in "lib/wrapunix.c".
 dnl
 AC_HEADER_STDC
-AC_CHECK_HEADERS(sys/types.h sys/time.h time.h errno.h fcntl.h limits.h signal.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h sys/stat.h unistd.h sys/wait.h sys/ipc.h sys/msg.h sys/sem.h sys/shm.h mqueue.h semaphore.h sys/mman.h sys/select.h poll.h stropts.h strings.h sys/ioctl.h sys/filio.h pthread.h door.h rpc/rpc.h sys/sysctl.h)
+AC_CHECK_HEADERS(stdint.h sys/types.h sys/time.h time.h errno.h fcntl.h limits.h signal.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h sys/stat.h unistd.h sys/wait.h sys/ipc.h sys/msg.h sys/sem.h sys/shm.h mqueue.h semaphore.h sys/mman.h sys/select.h poll.h stropts.h strings.h sys/ioctl.h sys/filio.h pthread.h door.h rpc/rpc.h sys/sysctl.h)

 dnl ##################################################################
 dnl Checks for typedefs.
```

Then run autoconf (use autoconf2.13 rather than a newer version), delete config.cache, and try again.

Comment: I saved your text as 'mypatch'. Then I ran patch -p1 < mypatch in the src directory. I got the following ouput - `patching file aclocal.m4
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file aclocal.m4.rej
patching file config.h.in
Hunk #1 FAILED at 2.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 49.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file config.h.in.rej
patching file configure.in`

Comment: *%$^ this book, might have been a classic two decades ago but I can't be bothered dealing with this crap, I'm gonna get a Linux specific book.

Comment: No no no! It's still a classic! I'm an experienced commercial developer and have read it cover to cover again and again, and I can say, it has its weaknesses, but is fantastic. You're using an older volume (the third edition of vol1, the useful volume, is much more modern). Regardless of what book you go for, you should never give in to the linux monoculture anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out these lines in **config.h** (execute `./configure` first):

```
#define uint8_t unsigned char         /* <sys/types.h> */
#define uint16_t unsigned short       /* <sys/types.h> */
#define uint32_t unsigned int         /* <sys/types.h> */
```

It works for me:).